# Bootstrap wysiwyg and syntax highlight

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, syntax-highlighting, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I trying to make new function in [Bootstrap wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) editor for inserting source code for **highlightjs**, but without success.

On official page (github) I have found few sentences about customizing and execCommand, but I do not know how to implement.

Anybody for help?

**EDIT**:
I successfully added button on toolbar like:

```
<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="insertCode"><i class="icon-code"></i>&nbsp;<i class="icon-angle-down icon-on-right"></i></a> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-light"> 
    <li><a data-edit="insertCode c">C/C++</li>
    <li><a data-edit="insertCode php">PHP</li>
</ul>
```

And I try to edit bootstrap-wysiwyg.js file as:

```
(function(b) {
   var insertCode = function (language) {
       var preElem = document.createElement("pre"),
       var codeElem = document.createElement("code");
       codeElem.className = language;
   }
...
...
```

But I do not know how to complete this. But before that I cannot run this method.

**EDIT 2:**:
I replaced my editor to summernote for now, because I do not know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I trying to add custom function insertCode into bootstrap-wysiwyg.js file, but unfortunately I do not know how, because in any case i getting errors. On Mozzila page for execCommand I have not found any example :(

Answer (score 0):

To add a button that will format the selection as code, you can add a link like this to the toolbar.

```
<a class="btn" data-edit="formatBlock pre" title="Code"><i class="icon-cog"></i></a>
```

However, I wasn't able to get this working with **highlightjs**.  I'm not sure that highlightjs is capable of picking up new `pre` tags that aren't present when the highlighter is initialized.  The other problem is that the button I provided wraps the code in a `<pre>` tag rather than a `<pre><code>` tag.

This might be enough to get you started though.